# How do I use React 15.5 with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

What's the proper way to use TypeScript and React together, now that they have extracted the PropTypes in a separate project with version 15.5?

Everything runs fine after upgrading from 15.4 to 15.5, except that now I get a this warning in the console: `"Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead."` How do I make it disappear?

I have tried doing the following steps, but it doesn't remove the console warning.

- Add the `prop-types` and `@types/prop-types` packages.
- Import PropTypes everywhere that I import React, `import * as PropTypes from "proptypes"`. Also tried with `require("prop-types")`.
- Turn off `noUnusedLocals`, to avoid that the compiler complains about PropTypes not being used.

---

**But**. Since I'm using TypeScript, the compiler is verifying the PropTypes at compile time, so I don't need to do the same at run time, and thus I shouldn't get the warning at all, right? I am hoping that maybe I can add or change a setting somewhere in the build configuration, that would make React compile without PropTypes.

Comment: Can you add a minimal setup/example that shows the warning?

Comment: @SebastianSebald: All I have right now is the full repository: https://github.com/janaagaard75/film-filter/tree/master/website. :-/

Comment: I don't have a firebase account, so I couldn't run you app. But since there is absolutely no use of `PropTypes` in your code, I guess that one of your dependencies (maybe `mobx`?) still uses them and this is why you get that warning.

Comment: I use a very similar set of dependencies (ts/webpack/react/mobx/mobx-react), I don't use prop-types at all, and on react 15.5 I don't get any such warning at runtime.  It may be prudent to setup a project with the same set of core dependencies, but not dependent on things like firebase to help identify where your problem is

Comment: @Alex: Thanks a lot for the info! At least now I know that it is possible to get my setup to work as intended. Do you have a link to your project?

Comment: @JanAagaard, no, I'm sorry, all the projects I work on are proprietary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: It's `mobx-react-devtools` that is causing the warning. The issue has been reported and fixed, but apparently not yet released.

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-devtools/issues/59

Comment: Thanks. I was also using mobx-react-devtools.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue because I was importing React as:

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

After I changed it to:

```
 import React from 'react'
```

everywhere in my project the warning disappeared.

There is no need for `prop-types` package.

P.S. I use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in tsconfig.json.

Comment: hmm how come can you `import React from 'react'` in TypeScript? that is only valid when using babel transpiler..

Comment: @apieceofbart If my answer was helpful don't be shy to upvote it ;)